# Windows 10 crashes, event 601, 41, 1101, 219, 1000 and 1001

Tags: windows-10, bsod, crash

My System keeps crashing under load, sometimes with BSOD but mostly it just hangs and i have to reboot manually. Sometimes while playing Dota2, but i can only recreate it intentionally with Keyshot6(CPU based 3D rendering) when i load a big file.
The same event ids keep showing in the event manager prior to the shutdown (601, 41, 1101, 219, 1000 and 1001).
After i shut down the system i usually can't restart right away, the monitor stays blank and i have to wait a few minutes before it works again.

Minidump: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_bETduPM1lTM2FqU1oxeEM4RFE

System:
Windows 10 Pro with all updates
Asus H170-Pro
i7-6700k
16GB RAM
all recently bought, new PSU aswell

Would appreciate it if someone could take a look at it, i opened the minidump with windbg but i have no idea what to look for.

Comment: You should use windbg, to analyze the driver at fault, and provide us the information so we can assist you

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately i don't know how to find out which driver is at fault. I'm using windbg for the first time and just tried !analyze -v but i can't make sense of the information i'm getting.

the error code in the eventviewer: 0x000000da (0x0000000000000504, 0xfffff6e800115a00, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000002b40).

Comment: With BlueScreenView i got the following Information:
Filename          : ntoskrnl.exe
Address In Stack  : ntoskrnl.exe+157fbd
From Address      : fffff802`3a873000
To Address        : fffff802`3b03d000
Size              : 0x007ca000
Time Stamp        : 0x57a1b615
Time String       : 03.08.2016 11:15:01
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
File Version      : 10.0.10586.545 (th2_release.160802-1857)
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
Full Path         : C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a complete dump, its a bit difficult to determine what exactly is the cause. The cause can be anywhere from driver issues to ram cards going bad.

The first thing is to go look for updated drivers. The hardware that could be the cause of this, would be your graphics card. Either way, you can use device manager to see hardware you have and the going to search drivers for said hardware. I recommend updating all drivers that you can find updates for. Even for printers you may have too

The next thing you should do is test your ram cards to see if they are going bad. Right click the start button, click run, and put `mdsched.exe`   . It will give you two options, either restart now to test, or schedule it to test your ram on next restart.

I also suggest changing your memory dump setting to complete memory dump. Although this is the largest memory dump, its the same size as the amount of ram you have. It provides the most details when you have a crash as it dumps everything from what the kernel was doing to what was in the ram at the time. To change this setting.

`Control Panel > System and Security > System. Click Advanced system settings. Under Startup and Recovery, click Settings.`

under write debugging, click on the drop down menu box, and change the memory dump type. This is optional, but if problem persists, it will give you more information than the other dump types will.

The other thing that could cause this, is malware/viruses. So if nothing else works, do a virus and malware scan.

Windows event number explanations:

601 -   Microsoft-Windows-PrintSpooler : failed to download and import printer driver

41 - The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first : Means it was forcefully rebooted, IE power button or Blue Screened.

1101 - Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy : Windows failed to locate the object for group policy.

219 - Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-PNP : Plug and Play device driver is failing to load. Could be USB drivers. Sometimes it could be the ISATAP drivers from microsoft.

1000 - Application Error. Means an Application is crashing.

1001 - Windows Reporting. Generates anytime there is a problem on your system.

Comment: After some crashes without dump i finally got a new BSOD with irql_not_less_or_equal so i thoroughly checked my ram and one of them seems to be faulty. After removing it i don't seem to have any Problems anymore.

Comment: @Jinthebandit  Since the diagnostics detected that it is faulty as well as you removing it resolved the crashes. Then I suggest replacing the ram card. Also as it seems to appear that your problem is now resolved, could you either mark any answers here that solved it for you, or if there isn't a suitable answer here to mark as the answer, asnwer your own question of what you did to fix the problem as well as marking it as the answer. This pretty much shows this question is closed and resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

You get the crash [SYSTEM_PTE_MISUSE (da)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560282(v=vs.85).aspx) which means a driver does some memory management errors.

Windbg tell me this help:

> A driver has corrupted system PTEs. Set
>   **HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory
>   Management\TrackPtes** to a **DWORD 3** value and reboot.  If the same
>   bugcheck occurs again the stack trace will identify the offending
>   driver.

So run `regedit.exe`, set the value `TrackPtes` to `3`, reboot and share the new dump.

Comment: Thank you, i don't have the TrackPtes entry. Should i add it? At the moment i don't have crashes anymore, after removing a faulty ram. But if the problem comes up again i'll try this. Thanks

Comment: yes, if the entry is not there create it. Wait a few days, faulty RAM can indeed cause the crashes,